# How to write a script to run 2 instances of CMD from shortcut and 2 python programs within (Win 10)?

Tags: python, shell, batch-file, windows-scripting

I'm writing a simple .bat script for Windows 10; I have the single parts working but not all together.
Basically I want a .bat file that:

1. launches a CMD shell from the  shortcut, something like `start "" "C:\Users............\System Tools\Command Prompt.lnk"`
2. in that shell, go to the folder of my python file `"cd C:\Users...........\myPython\` and executes `py  myFile.py %*`
3. Open a new CMD like at step one (possibly position it away from
   the first one so they don't overlap)
4. Change shell background color to **custom** color (I can do it with the default colors of `color NN` command)
5. Repeat step 2 for shell 2

Comment: how do you pass the arguments? %*

Comment: I don't have arguments to pass

Comment: Then why are you including `%*` in `py myFile.py %*`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely get what you want to do but you I think you can achieve it using some scripts:

For example you can have 3 bat files like that:

```
rem startboth.bat

start c:\path\to\my\folder\first.bat
start c:\path\to\my\folder\second.bat
```

```
rem first.bat

COLOR 4b
c:\Users\pnnp\Miniconda3\python.exe -v
```

```
rem second.bat

COLOR 4b
c:\Users\pnnp\Miniconda3\python.exe -m http.server
```

Than if you click on `both.bat` you will launch both processes in parallel with the wanted color.

Comment: Thanks. So basically I need to open 2 instances of a python program. And every time I need to open cmd twice (change the color of the second one), go to a long path in each shell, run py.
Your solution is almost there but, is it possible to have only 1 script instead of 3?
As for the color I want to use a generic RGB (or HEX) for the background, instead of one of those defined by default, something like (12FA4D instead of 4B)

Comment: For the generic RGB you have to check dos shell documentation.
For having only one I don't know if this is possible because every command is executed in another shell, so you will not have color. But you can put the other 2 scripts in a folder that does not spawn the desktop, even in the python folder.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, and subsequent comments, this is my best guess for your batch file content:

```sh
@Start "Shell 1" /D "%UserProfile%\myPython" "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /D /K "py.exe myFile.py"
@Start "Shell 2" /D "%UserProfile%\myPython" "%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe" /D /T:E5 /K "py.exe myFile.py"
```

I'll assume that you should be able to adjust the titles, file paths, and color combination, yourself, *based upon the usage information for the `start` and `cmd` commands, (i.e. `start /?`, and `cmd /?`).*